# Automatically opening Chrome tracer on an input file?

Tags: google-chrome, timeline, trace

The Chrome web browser contains a powerful tracer tool, which not only allows tracing and debugging web pages but also allows your own programs to create a specially formatted JSON file and display it as a visual timeline of events in your program, which is extremely useful for debugging performance bottlenecks in a multiprocess/multithreaded system. I am trying to make this tool as accessible and hassle free as possible for users.

Suppose I have created a JSON file in my external program, and now I wish to view it in the tracer. The steps would be:

- Open a Chrome window or tab.
- Type `chrome://tracing` in the URL bar.
- Click 'Load', browse to my file, and open.

My question is: Can this process be automated from the command line? I have looked it up and found nothing. Perhaps some javascript wizardry is required here.

For background reading:

- http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/176420/Indepth_Using_Chrometracing_to_view_your_inline_profiling_data.php
- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CvAClvFfyA5R-PhYUmn5OOQtYMH4h6I0nSsKchNAySU/preview#

If you want an example input file for the tracer, copy the following text and name it `mytimeline.json`. Follow the steps above to view it.

```
[ {"cat":"1", "pid":1000,"tid":1001,"ts":100000,"ph":"B","name":"UpdateLayoutTree","args":{"timestamp-s":"jun 2 12:12:12","frame":10034} }
, {"cat":"1", "pid":1000,"tid":1001,"ts":102000,"ph":"B","name":"subfunc","args":{"timestamp-e":"jun 2 12:12:13", "elementCount":4} }
, {"cat":"1", "pid":1000,"tid":1001,"ts":108000,"ph":"E","args":{"timestamp-e":"jun 2 12:12:13"} }
, {"cat":"1", "pid":1000,"tid":1001,"ts":110000,"ph":"E","args":{"timestamp-e":"jun 2 12:12:13"} }
, {"cat":"1", "pid":1000,"tid":1002,"ts":120000,"dur":15000,"ph":"X","name":"Something","args":{"elementCount":4} }
, {"cat":"2", "pid":1003,"tid":1004,"ts":125000,"ph":"i","name":"Boom","args":{"elementCount":4}, "s": "t" }
]
```